# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) when using split()

Tags: python

I keep getting this error:

```
x, y, z = expression.split(" ") 
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

This is my code:

```
expression = input("Expression: ")
# Parse variables.
x, y, z = expression.split(" ")
new_x=float(x)
new_z=float(z)
#calculate
if y == "+":
    result = new_x + new_z
if y == "-":
    result = new_x - new_z
if y == "*":
    result = new_x * new_z
if y == "/":
    result= new_x / new_z
print(round(result, 1))
```

Comment: By the sound of it, your input doesn't contain any spaces

Comment: This code is expecting input like `2 + 3`, with exactly two spaces in it.  What did you actually enter?

Answer (score 1):

it means that `expression.split(" ")` returns only one value, but since you unpacked its value to three variables `x,y,z`, it should return three values. So the problem is actually with your input.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the input does not have enough delimited fragments to split into three pieces. You can play with this in the REPL:

```
>>> x, y, z = "a b c".split(" ")
>>> x
'a'
>>> y
'b'
>>> z
'c'
>>> x, y, z = "a b".split(" ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
>>> x, y, z = "a".split(" ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

For your use case where you are accepting input, the best bet is to handle this specific exception.

```
valid_input = false
x, y, z = None, None, None
while not valid_input:
  try:
    expression = input("Expression: ")
    x, y, z = expression.split(" ")
    valid_input = true
  except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input provided. Be sure to provide input with exactly 2 spaces in it!")

...  # Continue with the rest of your code
```

Another way to do this is:

```
def input_expression(attempt: int = 0) -> [str, str, str]:
  if attempt > 3:
    raise Exception("Too many invalid attempts. Quitting.")
  try:
    expression = input("Expression: ")
    x, y, z = expression.split(" ")
    return x, y, z
  except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input provided. Be sure to provide input with exactly 2 spaces in it!")
    return input_expression(attempt + 1)

x, y, z = input_expression()
... # The rest of your code
```